# How does one use Bloomberg in r after it connects?

Tags: r, bloomberg

I have never used r before, and my lecturer gave me some [code](https://pastebin.com/AHMYper3) to run to get data off Bloomberg. It seems to go fine, except the output stops at

> BLOOMBERG COMMUNICATION SERVER READY on Port: 8194

and does nothing after that. I am at a Bloomberg terminal, and have logged in to the terminal.

In the [code](https://pastebin.com/AHMYper3), the program doesn't seem to go past `system("C:/blp/DAPI/bbcomm.exe")` and onto the next line `library(Rblpapi)`.

[image]

When I try running more code after the `BLOOMBERG COMMUNICATION SERVER READY on Port: 8194`, the `>` symbol does not appear on the left, and it seems to be doing nothing.

I'm a complete noob, so pointers in the right direction are appreciated. Otherwise I'll just have to try to download the data manually, but I would like to learn more about how to do this with r.

Comment: Try: `system("C:/blp/DAPI/bbcomm.exe", wait = FALSE)` but you should provide this feedback to the course instructor. By default `system()` will block the console for long-/permanent-running processes and they should know that esp since they seem to be fairly "old school" R folk from the snippet you linked to.

Comment: Ok, but now after `con <- blpConnect()` I get `Error in blpConnect_Impl(host, port) : Failed to start session.`

Comment: Then it's "go back to instructor" time. I suspect a scant few folks on SO have access to a local Bloomberg terminal to triage the issue.